# Spark/Hadoop - Unable to find SASL server implementation for DIGEST-MD5

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

for hours now I try to set up Hadoop/YARN so I can execute Spark programs on it.

But I'm stuck with an error for which I find absolutely nothing.

When I try a spark-submit or spark-shell command with --master yarn I get the following exception:

```
Application application_1481891851677_0002 failed 2 times due to Error launching appattempt_1481891851677_0002_000002. 
Got exception: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Unable to find SASL server implementation for DIGEST-MD5
```

I used the configurations from the beginner tutorials of spark and hadoop:

**core-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>
```

**hdfs-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
</property>
```

**yarn-site.xml**

```
    <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>
```

I did not enable SASL anywhere. Does someone know how I'd go about fixing or at least circumventing the error?

Answer (score 0):

I figure out that it is the problem of jdk version. I got this error when my mapReduce jobs working on Hadoop 2.8 with openjdk-9. After I change it to openjdk-8 or openjdk-7, it works well.